# I want to make this eye blink

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, vertex-groups, inverse-kinematics

I have modeled a little doggy and I wanna make her eyes blink. What I have created are two quarter spheres that set at the back of the eye behind the mesh to roll on the x-axis over the eyeball.

[image]

[image]

I have tried using shape-keys, but that deforms the mesh. I have tried adding a bone to the eye lids but that deforms them further. I am a "noob" at this and could really use some detailed instructions on how to remedy this.

Thank you.

- Sam

Comment: Can't you just rotate the meshes? I don't think there's any need for rigging or shapekeys.

Comment: I could do that, but surely there is a more efficient way to animate it.

Comment: Okay, so I think I have it figured out. I made an empty between the two eyes and set a rotation constraint (locally) to the empty. I did inverse x axis on the two bottom lids and now all four are controlled by one unit.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say *objects*, not *meshes*.